# Access doesn't want to open any databases

Tags: ms-access, automation

I have a virtual PC running access databases that trigger different scripts and pulls for the office in the morning for a few years now.  Not sure why but as of Thursday the 14th, whenever the virtual PC tries to open a database, it goes directly to the Open Screen for selection of recently used databases.  If you select any of them, it goes right back to the same screen of open recent files.  It doesn't want to open anything.
I have tried repair office, got to open one accdb file before running into the same issue again.  Tried uninstall/re-install for the same result.  I can open the same databases on any other machine other than this one with this automated user.  I can even have any other user on the same machine open them without issue.  This issue is literally a limited for this one user on this one machine and have no idea how/why it is this way as nothing gets changed on this machine, it's strictly for this purpose of running scripts.

Comment: Hard to guess - but I would re-boot the computer - sometime a stray copy of Access remains running - keeps the file open in exclusive mode. So, any additional attempts to run/load the application will fair. So, re-boot - it will clear out any stray running copy of access that may well have not shut down.

Comment: unfortunately, that didn't do anything as I had to reboot just during the repair and uninstall/re-install processes.  I just haven't seen anything like this and couldn't find anything on the internet even remotely close to the issue.  It's just really odd.

Comment: It looks like it might have something to do with the Office updates from Wednesday the 13th.  If I have any user try to open the databases from a triggered event like a bat file or cmd file, their access gets corrupt and doesn't work anymore.  If any user opens them manually, it works fine.  Basically whatever Microsoft did to add security features, screwed up my chances for automation.